# video/audio output via HDMI Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, video, 64-bit, hdmi

I've been out of the Ubuntu loop for quite a while now and have a completely new laptop now.  Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and would like to output my video and my audio via HDMI to my television.  the following is the `lspci | grep VGA` for my computer.  please tell me if there is any additional information needed and preferably how to obtain it and i will be more than happy to oblige.  thank you in advance for your time and assistance in this matter.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Edit: every time i restart my computer, after a short moment, i get an error message stating something along the lines "sorry, jockey needed to close unexpectedly." after researching, i discovered jockey is the name of the "additional drivers," which after initial installation, ubuntu informed me of proprietary drivers available.  those are no longer available, and this error continues to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Good day, lostNfound.

I have the same problem, although with a different NVIDIA graphics card.
I was also having jockey/additional drivers crash. Since recent updates, it no longer crashes but I still can't display to my HDTV via HDMI port.

Mega sadface.

I've been trying to sort this out on and off for some time and it's been quite a ball ache, so much so that I'm starting to regret not having paid £60 for the Windows 7 licence...

Anyway, here's as far as I've got so far:

Additional Drivers application presents me with 4 drivers, which I can activate one at a time. The Ubuntu 12.04 application has never detected anything other than the HP monitor I am using at the moment.

Online, I found that one needs the NVIDIA X Server Settings application to work and NVIDIA GPU properly. Everyone seems to agree that's the way to go. Try

> sudo nvidia-settings

which should allow to establish if you already have it installed. I'm afraid I don't recall how I installed it myself. Like I said, I've been on this for some time and tried many things!

I went to the NVIDIA website and downloaded the appropriate driver for my graphics card & OS. This was a .run file. I had some serious issues installing from this, it wasn't user friendly (I am not an Ubuntu expert, but not a complete novice either) I eventually succeeded by following the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/484991/nvidia-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-12-04)
I've no idea what CUDA is, but the installation was successful.

NVIDIA X Server Settings correctly identifies the driver version that is installed.
However, the Detect Displays button still fails to detect my telly.

See if it works for you and good luck!